# How to authenticate a Firebase user in a Polymer custom element?

Tags: firebase, polymer-1.0, firebase-authentication, polymerfire

I have a Polymer application in which I want to use Firebase auth. I have created a custom element with a `<paper-dialog>` with email and password form.

If I include `<firebase-app>` and `<firebase-auth>` elements in the custom element, I am able to authenticate the user. So far, so good.

The problem arises when I want to sign the user out from the application, with a button/function in the root element. I need to get hold of the `<firebase-auth>` element in order to call its `signOut` method. I find the `<firebase-auth>` element with `$.id` or `$$('#id')` but it returns null.

If I move the `<firebase-auth>` and `<firebase-app>` elements into the root element, then I have the same problem trying to access them from my custom sign-in element.

If I add just the `<firebase-auth>` element to both places, I get `'No app configured for auth'` and if I add the `<firebase-app>` element to both as well, I get `'Default app already defined'`.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Can you put a sample of your actual code that isn't working? From your description it's not clear exactly where the problem lies.

Comment: The problem is that I have tried several solutions as described but am not able to make any of them work. I'm not sure that I can add code for each of the options.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a solution with authentication being handled in my `<signin-dialog>`. What worked for me was to leave `<firebase-app>` and `<firebase-auth>` in my top-level `<app>` element, then fire an event from `<signin-dialog>` and call the `<firebase-auth>` signIn menthod from the evenHandler in the `<app>`:

```
<app>
<iron-ajax auto url="https://apiserver/config" handle-as="json" last-response="{{config}}"></iron-ajax>

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{config}}">
          <firebase-app auth-domain="{{config.fbWebConfig.authDomain}}" database-url="{{config.fbWebConfig.databaseURL}}" api-key="{{config.fbWebConfig.apiKey}}">
          </firebase-app>
          <firebase-auth id="auth" name='auth' user="{{user}}" on-error="handleAuthError">
          </firebase-auth>
            <signin-dialog user={{user}}></signin-dialog>
        </template>  
</app>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your button function you can just call the following JavaScript to sign the user out of Firebase:

```
firebase.auth().signOut();
```